# Developing a Windows Mobile Component for displaying Thumbnails

Tags: windows-mobile

I require to develop this Windows Mobile Control for displaying thumbnails in a List So that the user go and select an Image...

Any article code snippet is really Appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Here, this is one I've used before that works nicely:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/337a210b-ba43-4f2a-b5a3-4121fae7dee4